# Bundling module for NODE.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, bundle

ASP.NET MVC 4 has brought amazing tool for bundling multiple stylesheets or javascripts into one like this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

Does *NODE.JS* have any modules to fulfil the same task - to bundle **client** javascript libraries into one? I've seen tools like browserify, uglifier, etc. but these require manual invocation of console commands (or may I have missed something?). Meanwhile, it would be nice to eliminate that excessive step and have middleware that could be easily integrated into *express.js* application, for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several attempts to implement this, you can try them out and see which works best for you: [bundle-up](https://github.com/Cowboy-coder/bundle-up), [brewer.js](https://github.com/matehat/brewer.js), [connect-assetmanager](https://github.com/mape/connect-assetmanager)

Answer (score 2):

Not to mention automatic complication of stylus files into a single css file, also usable as express middleware.

Search npm for 'asset' and I'm sure you can find tons of these.

Comment: By the way, asp.net is probably the last framework to have included an asset pipeline manager. So I wouldn't give then to much credit. :P

Comment: Indeed, and to make matters worse every time they reinvents the wheel they tries to come up with new name for it. Hence googling for 'bundles' instead of 'assets' got me nowhere..

Comment: Asset is actually the correct term. ASP.NET is the one using the wrong term. Here are examples from rails: http://mintdigital.github.com/asset_hat/, https://github.com/documentcloud/jammit/, php: https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic, and python: http://elsdoerfer.name/docs/webassets/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [bl-bundler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bl-bundler). It also supports integration with express.js